# Junit test for lastIndexOf(Object elem, int index)

Tags: java, junit4

```
public synchronized int lastIndexOf(Object elem, int index) {
        if (index >= elementCount)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " >= "+ elementCount);

    if (elem == null) {
        for (int i = index; i > 0; i--)
        if (elementData[i]==null)
            return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = index; i > 0; i--)
        if (elem.equals(elementData[i]))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
    }
```

Iam trying to write Junit test for this with 100% braanch coverage.What is the Junit test case for this?

Comment: Test _case_? Don't you mean test **_cases_** (plural)? You have to test each boundary (_min_, _max_) out of bound values (_min_ - some amount and _max_ + some amount), as well as arbitrary values inside the range. Then, you need to test exceptions. You can probably come up with 10 test cases for that function alone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: No need for the test, the code is buggy by inspection :-)  Consider the case when elementData contains one object, 'x', and you're looking for 'x'.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using xpath and get last element:
Examples xpath:

```
(//element[@name='D'])[last()]
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.